# Make code available to other subclasses and subsubclasses

Tags: java, constructor, subclass, abstract, superclass

I made a SuperClass (Abstract), a Subclass (Abstract) and a SubSubClass.

There is a piece of code I want to keep in the constructor of the SuperClass, but it won't work correctly unless I put it the Subclass instead.

The SuperClass:

```
public abstract class SuperClass{

protected int x, y, halfX, halfY;

public SuperClass(){
    halfX = x / 2;
    halfY = y / 2;
}
```

The SubClass:

```
public abstract class SubClass extends SuperClass{

public SubClass(int x, int y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
```

The SubSubClass:

```
public class SubSubClass extends SubClass{

int half;

public SubSubClass(int x, int y){
    super(x, y);
}

public void myMethod(){
    half = halfX + halfY;
}
```

If I remove the `halfX = x / 2;` `halfY = y / 2;` from the SuperClass constructor and put it into the Subclass constructor, the code works. Like this:

```
public abstract class SubClass() extends SuperClass{

public SubClass(int x, int y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    halfX = x / 2;
    halfY = y / 2;
}
}
```

I want that piece of code available for other subclasses (and subsubclasses) instead of only in that subclass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as you called `super(x, y);` in `SubSubClass`, you need to do the same thing in `SubClass`.  There is no magic to it, just pass the values to the SuperClass so that `x` and `y` will be set before you attempt to calculate half the value.

I highly recommend making your fields `final` where ever possible and in this case they should be `final`.

BTW: If you want to see what is happening you can step through your code in your debugger.

```
public abstract class SuperClass{

    protected final int x, y, halfX, halfY;

    public SuperClass(int x, int y){
        this.x = x; // set x before using it.
        this.y = y; // set y before using it.
        halfX = x / 2;
        halfY = y / 2;
    }
}

public abstract class SubClass extends SuperClass{

    private final int z;

    public SubClass(int x, int y, int z){
        super(x, y);
        // only set fields of SubClass
        this.z = z;
    }
```

Comment: Hmm thank you for the answer. I think the reason I got stuck, is because I have a code that would add more arguments to the subclass.

If I where to add 2-3 extra arguments in subclass, how would I approach it?

Comment: @Talabo if the SubClass has more arguments than the SuperClass, you should pass less arguments to the SuperClass and handle the extra arguments in the SubClass.

Comment: Thank you :) I'll look up on how to add more arguments in subclass :)

Comment: @Talabo I added it to my answer. You need to have a constructor in the sub-class with more arguments.

Comment: My bad, Thank you so much for the help. I can finally go to sleep with one less worry tonight :)

Comment: @Talabo Things often make more sense after a good sleep. Good night ;)

Answer (score 0):

By default the `super()` invokes constructor from the super class in `Subclass` constructor before you assign:

```
   this.x = x;
   this.y = y;
```

thus you are dividng zeroes which is default value for int field. That's why `halfX` and `halfY` are 0.

`x,y` are part of your `SuperClass` so they should be initilized there.

Comment: Thank you. I might have been to focused on putting it up differently than that. The idea would then be to add more arguments to the subclass constructor after the superclass, so my question would then be little different I guess :)